# How to get access to the update immutability helper in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, requirejs

I've found on [this documentation page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) that there is an update immutability helper that I can make use of.  The only thing is that I'm confused about how to get access to it within my ASP.NET MVC project.  I simply don't know how to get access to the code for `update()`.

I have installed the ReactJS Nuget package and I've had the following bundle config that I include into any pages that need the ReactJS library.

```
// ReactJS bundle
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/reactjs")
       .Include("~/Scripts/react-with-addons.js",
       "~/Scripts/react-dom.js"));
```

At first I was getting the error `update is not defined`.  It then became obvious to me that I need to define it as is shown within the documentation - it looks like I have to use RequireJS.

JavaScript code

```
var update = require('react-addons-update');
```

I've installed RequireJS and I'm getting the following error now:

> require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Module name "react-addons-update" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Sadly I'm not familiar with RequireJS, but I have scanned the documentation.  Initially I assumed that RequireJS would load the files [from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-update), because it's the only place that it seems to be mentioned on the web when I search Google, however I've soon come to realise that I have to have the scripts in a location within my file system.

So now I'm left searching for the correct file to include so that I can get an instance of `update()`.  I've searched the Github that the NPM links to but it takes me to the entire ReactJS repository.

I'm quite familiar with JavaScript but this one has left me baffled.

How can I get to the source of `react-addons-update` to include in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like because I'm including `react-with-addons.js` I am able to access the helper through the following code:

```
var update = React.addons.update;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner to ensure that your code could be used when addons is removed in a future version of React.

Creating a react-addons-update.js containing the following will do it:

```
define(["react"], function(r) {
    return r.addons.update;
});
```

Or if you want to do this for multiple addons but not create a separate file for each, then you could create a file: react-addon-modules.js:

```
define("react-addons-create-fragment", ["react"], function (r) {
    return r.addons.createFragment;
});
define("react-addons-transition-group", ["react"], function (r) {
    return r.addons.TransitionGroup;
});
define("react-addons-update", ["react"], function (r) {
    return r.addons.update;
});
```

And then in requireJS config ensure you have:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "react-addons-create-fragment": "react-addon-modules",
        "react-addons-transition-group": "react-addon-modules",
        "react-addons-update": "react-addon-modules"
    }
});
```